# Using ExternalProject to build GLFW in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, glfw, visual-studio-2015

I am using CMake for a project of mine which uses GLFW. I used ExternalProject to build GLFW.

```
# GLFW
ExternalProject_Add(
    glfw
    PREFIX "contrib"
    URL "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/glfw/glfw-3.0.4.zip"
    CMAKE_ARGS -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/glfw
    INSTALL_COMMAND make DESTDIR=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib install
)
set(GLFW_STATIC_LIB "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/glfw/lib/libglfw3.a")
set(GLFW_LIBRARIES "-lX11 -lXrandr -lXi -lXxf86vm")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -isystem ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/glfw/include")
```

This works fine in linux. However now I want to build my project in windows. I am unsure what I need to change. When I build it like that with VS14, it says something like `the command "make" is either written incorrectly oder could not be found`. I googled around a bit and used nmake instead. But then it says `NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'install'`. I then added a `\f` after nmake and then it says `NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'DESTDIR=C:/Users/gartenriese/Source/Repos/monoengine/contrib' not found` but the directory definitely does exist.

How do I do it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Visual Studio doesn't need an INSTALL_COMMAND. Without it, everything gets build and I can run the application.